Why does sign of eigenvector flip for small covariance change?
The 2 covariance matrices only differ by values at top-right and bottom-left. However, sign of principal component eigen vectors (right column) has flipped.
import numpy as np


cov = np.array([[9369, 7060,   16469],
               [7060,  8127,   23034],
               [16469, 23034,  126402]])

eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eigh(cov)

print('Cov 1')
print(eigenvalues)
print(eigenvectors)

cov2 = np.array([[9369, 7060,   *18969*],
               [7060,   8127,   23034],
               [*18969*,  23034,  126402]])

eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eigh(cov2)

print('Cov 2')
print(eigenvalues)
print(eigenvectors)

Results:
Cov 1
[  1188.72951707   9507.3058357  133201.96464723]
[[-0.5549483   0.82002403  0.13997491]
 [ 0.8280924   0.52849364  0.18696912]
 [-0.07934332 -0.21967035  0.97234231]]
Cov 2
[  1390.92828009   8581.02234156 133926.04937835]
[[-0.57175381  0.80502124 -0.15823521]
 [ 0.817929    0.54427789 -0.18642352]
 [-0.06395096 -0.23601353 -0.96964318]]

How can I either prevent this happening, or 'correct' in some way so that sign is same - either positive or negative in both cases?
EDIT:
Does anyone have c# aswell?
Can someone tell me if the above issue happens with mathnet.numerics.evd()?

The essential thing to realize here is: The sign of an eigenvector is arbitrary, i.e. if v is an eigenvector of matrix cov, then so is -v (see for example this related discussion on Cross Validated). So, given your question, both results for the slightly altered matrices cov and cov2 are correct (just in case you doubted this). Putting it differently: given your question Why does sign of eigenvector flip for small covariance change?, one might be tempted to counter Why should the sign stay the same?.
If you want to resolve the ambiguous sign, you need to do that yourself; for example, by

choosing it such that the largest vector component is always positive (which might likewise be ambiguous, e.g. if multiple vector components have the same absolute value); or
as proposed by @Lrx, by fixing the sign of the first non-zero component (which might be unstable, given that a "true zero", i.e. the zero of an analytical solution, might be a tiny non-zero value in a numerical solution); or
as stated in my comment below, by choosing either v or -v, depending on which of the two maximizes the dot product with a reference vector (which might be ambiguous and unstable, as well).

The approach that will work for you depends on the underlying problem that you actually want to solve, I guess. The best idea, in my opinion, would be finding an approach (for the underlying problem, that is) that does not rely on a certain sign configuration in the eigendecomposition in the first place.

I understand what you are getting at but I have not found a foolproof algorithm that will  orientate the sign consistently. There always appear to be one or 2 cases that fall through as with algorithm proposed by @Lrx

@Lrx I see the problem. If I recall correctly I had a similar problem once before. In my particular case, I wanted to produce vector fields of smoothly varying eigenvectors, and I ended up fixing the sign of one and then adjusing the sign of neighboring eigenvectors by choosing either -v or v, depending on which maximized the dot product with the reference vector. That's essentially what I meant by saying: (1) the approach you will end up with depends on the actual underlying problem and (2) best find a solution for the underlying problem that doesn't rely on the sign at all (if possible).

Would you post that code please

@ManInMoon I don't have that code any more, I am afraid. I used it in a project during studies years ago.

Sorry for referencing the wrong author in my comment above, by the way.

In the end, I think the only reliable (but not so elegant) solution is to write a function to manually do the check (here, I impose for each vector in the matrix to have its first coordinate being positive. If it is null, I check the second, and so on.):
def adjust_eigenvectors(eigenvectors : np.ndarray):
    n,m = eigenvectors.shape
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if eigenvectors[j, i] > 0:
                break
            elif eigenvectors[j, i] < 0:
                eigenvectors[:, i] = -eigenvectors[:, i]
                break

    return eigenvectors

eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eigh(cov2)
print('Cov 2')
print(eigenvalues)
print(adjust_eigenvectors(eigenvectors))

Note that this function does it in place AND returns the value, so technically, there is no need to write return eigenvectors as it has already been modified.
I don't really like this solution as it's not vectorized (let alone numpy-styled), but it fix the solution.

UPLO='U' does not work everytime - sadly

Again, with the above altered answer, it may work in this case but doesn't in every case. Thanks for the attempt though.
